# TableCell hyperlink not aligning correctly on TableView - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have this problem with the first `Hyperlink` being alignment on top of `TableCell`.
I have tried almost everything and I could not get it to work.

[image]

```
colData.setCellFactory(e -> {
        return new TableCell<TabelaShitjet, Hyperlink>(){
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Hyperlink item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (!empty){
                    item.setOnAction(e -> {
                        TeDhenatBlerjes(Integer.parseInt(getTableView().getColumns().get(0).getCellData(getTableRow().getIndex())+""), item.getText());
                    });
                    setGraphic(item);
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

CONSTRUCTOR

```
public class TabelaShitjet {
    private Hyperlink data;

    public TabelaShitjet(String data){
        this.data = new Hyperlink(data);
    }

    public Hyperlink getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Hyperlink data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got no idea why exactly this happens, but if you remove the graphic when cell becomes empty by setting it to `null`, the problem seems to be fixed.

You should undo any modifications done to a cell when a item is added on a call of `updateItem` where the cell becomes empty anyway, since otherwise empty cells could be shown as if they were non-empty:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(Hyperlink item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (!empty){
        item.setOnAction(e -> {
            TeDhenatBlerjes(Integer.parseInt(getTableView().getColumns().get(0).getCellData(getTableRow().getIndex())+""), item.getText());
        });
    }

    // set graphic every time i.e. set it to null for empty cells
    setGraphic(item);
}
```

---

In general the `updateItem` method should be implemented like this:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(ItemType item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (empty) {
        // undo any updates that could have been made
        // to make the cell look different from the empty cell
    } else {
        // update cell to display item
    }
}
```